# How to get sidebar full length of page below top navigation with bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

New to bootstrap and using the alpha version of bootstrap 4 to create a site for my home network.

I'd like the sidebar to fill the entire left side of the page, starting below the top nav bar. Right now there is a small 20 or so pixel gap between the top navbar and sidebar. I'd also like it to continue all the way down, despite the size of the page.

I'm using the admin template from bootstrap and modified it to my needs.

https://jsfiddle.net/ced6ee78/

CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

/* BrandName Top Navbar */
.so-navbar-top {
    background-color: #087ca7;
    height: 48px;
}

.so-navbar-top .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.so-navbar-top .nav-item {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

/* BrandName Sidebar */
.so-sidebar {
  background-color: #13293d;
}

/* workaround modal-open padding issue */

body.modal-open {

padding-right: 0 !important;

}




#sidebar {

padding-left:0;

}



/*

* Off Canvas at medium breakpoint

* --------------------------------------------------

*/


@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {


  .row-offcanvas {

    position: relative;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;

    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;

    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;

  }



  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {

    left: -33%;
  }



  .row-offcanvas-left.active {

    left: 33%;

    margin-left: -6px;

  }



  .sidebar-offcanvas {

    position: absolute;

    top: 0;

    width: 33%;

    height: 100%;

  }

}



/*

* Off Canvas wider at sm breakpoint

* --------------------------------------------------

*/


@media screen and (max-width: 34em) {

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {

    left: -45%;

  }



  .row-offcanvas-left.active {

    left: 45%;

    margin-left: -6px;

  }



  .sidebar-offcanvas {

    width: 45%;

  }

}



.card {

    overflow:hidden;

}



.card-block .rotate {

    z-index: 8;

    float: right;

    height: 100%;

}



.card-block .rotate i {

    color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.15);

    position: absolute;

    left: 0;

    left: auto;

    right: -10px;

    bottom: 0;

    display: block;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-44deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(-44deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(-44deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(-44deg);
    transform: rotate(-44deg);

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/brandname/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <title>Dashboard | BrandName</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-fade mb-3 so-navbar-top">

      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="flex-row d-flex">

        <a class="navbar-brand mb-1" href="#" title="ServiceOps">BrandName</a>

        <button type="button" class="hidden-md-up navbar-toggler" data-toggle="offcanvas" title="Toggle responsive left sidebar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">1</span> Alerts</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="main">

      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 sidebar-offcanvas so-sidebar" id="sidebar" role="navigation">

          <ul class="nav flex-column pl-1">

            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item">

              <a class="nav-link" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">Sites</a>

              <ul class="list-unstyled flex-column pl-3 collapse" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="false">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Item 2</a></li>
              </ul>

            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10 main">

          <!--toggle sidebar button
          <p class="hidden-md-up">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-sm" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Menu</button>
          </p>-->

          <h1 class="display-2 hidden-xs-down">Dashboard</h1>

          <div class="row mb-3">

            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">

              <div class="card card-inverse card-success">

                <div class="card-block bg-success">

                  <div class="rotate">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
                  </div>

                  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Users</h6>
                  <h1 class="display-1">134</h1>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">

              <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">

                <div class="card-block bg-danger">

                  <div class="rotate">

                    <i class="fa fa-list fa-4x"></i>

                  </div>

                  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Posts</h6>
                  <h1 class="display-1">87</h1>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">

              <div class="card card-inverse card-info">

                <div class="card-block bg-info">

                  <div class="rotate">

                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x"></i>

                  </div>

                  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Tweets</h6>
                  <h1 class="display-1">125</h1>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">

              <div class="card card-inverse card-warning">

                <div class="card-block bg-warning">

                  <div class="rotate">

                    <i class="fa fa-share fa-5x"></i>

                  </div>

                  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Shares</h6>
                  <h1 class="display-1">36</h1>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <footer class="container-fluid">

      <p class="text-right small">&copy;2017 BrandName</p>

    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding-top` on `body` should be the same height as your navbar.

In this case:

```
body { padding-top: 48px; }
```

If you need more spacing for the content in the left nav and main content area, add padding/margin to `.so-sidebar` and `.main`.

Comment: Sweet! This removes the gap on the top, but how do I make the sidebar the full length even though the page is shorter than a full screen?

Comment: That part seems to be working already according to your jsfiddle: it starts at the top nav and ends at the footer.

Do you want to overlap the footer?

Comment: See here: http://imgur.com/a/Da6cD  It stops right at the footer. It should go all the way to the bottom of the browser window. I also don't mind pushing the footer to the bottom if need be.

Comment: Ah yeah, I had to copy your code to my local machine to see the problem. You will probably have to re-do your html and css to get what you want.

I did a similar off-canvas menu on my personal websit (https://ajmaxwell.com), feel free to poke around. This method uses the `vh` unit (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) and was built using Bootstrap 4 alpha.4, current is alpha.6, so things might be different...

Once I get home I should have more time to adapt my code to yours

Answer (score 0):

1. The gap between the header and sidebar is caused by `padding-top: 70px;` on the body, which causes everything besides for the fixed header to be `70px` from the top of the page.

You need this rule to prevent all other elements from starting behind your fixed header, however, to prevent any gap, give it the exact height of your header.

```
padding-top: 48px;
```

2. To make the sidebar take up the entire length of the page, give it a minimum height of `100vh` minus the body's padding (header's height)

You can do that with CSS3's `calc()`:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
```

With this layout, you can put the footer together with the rest of the app to prevent it from appearing below the sidebar.

Here's a [jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kLsykby4/1/)

The other option would be adding `position: fixed` to the sidebar, and adding padding/margins so the rest of the elements don't overlap.

Comment: I moved the `<footer></footer>` code below the div within the app to give the sidebar ability to fill the whole page. Still not able to get it to stick.

Comment: Did you see the jsFiddle above?

Comment: I was able to get it to work, however, if the sidebar content fills up with more links and the scroll bar appears, the rest of the links get a white background.

Comment: Sorry, in the jsFiddle I used `height` instead of `min-height` - which allows the sidebar to take up more than the specified height when the content calls for it.  I've updated the jsFiddle, so it should work now.  You can see it here with many links added: https://jsfiddle.net/8mwqr118/